# jQuery Mobile - Keep layout grid vertically aligned

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery Mobile (JQM) layout grids for a form validation project. The problem is that when I add an error above one of the fields, the other field in the same grid looks misaligned vertically:

[image]

I would like to keep the fields inline regardless of errors above them, preferably using css/HTML/JQM only. The error messages have to remain within the ui-block-a or b divs.

Here is the HTML. There is no css styling outside of what JQM provides by default:

```
<div class="ui-grid-a">
    <div class="ui-block-a">
        <label>
            City:
            <input type="text"/>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b">
        <div class="field-validation-error">The State field is required</div>
        <label>
            State:
            <select>
                <option selected="selected">Select a state...</option>
            </select>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried the following css override, but it ends up hiding the error message.

```
.ui-grid-a {
position: relative;
}

.ui-block-a {
padding-right: 7px;
}

.ui-block-b {
padding-left: 7px;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: I've also tried css - whitespace: nowrap but doesn't work with the css used by JQM will work with this.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are hiding and showing the respective error divs on submit.

http://jsfiddle.net/B95jE/1/

```
<div class="error-div"> 
    <div class="state-validation-error">The State field is required</div>
    <div class="city-validation-error">The city field is required</div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="ui-grid-a">
    <div class="ui-block-a">
        <label>
            City:
            <input type="text"/>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b">
        <label>
            State:
            <select>
                <option selected="selected">Select a state...</option>
            </select>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.error-div{
    position:relative;
}
.ui-grid-a {
position: relative;
}

.ui-block-a {
float: left;
}

.ui-block-b {
float: right;
}

.state-validation-error{
    float:right;
}

.city-validation-error{
    float:left;
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Ah not quite I'm afraid. The field errors have to be inside the ui-block div, like in my example HTML. I think part of the problem is that JQM creates its own divs with its own styling around each input element.